# Showing two tables content in one table. Binding. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, annotations, javafx-8

I have two tables which are mapped and linked (PositionResource and PositionCurrency), I want to bind them in one table, so that two columns are from one table and one column from another. I've done this work:

```
    @FXML
    private TableView<PositionResource> tv_loro_nostro_accounts;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PositionResource, String> tc_account;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PositionResource, String> tc_acc_name;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<PositionCurrency, String> tc_currency;
```

and binding is as follows. Relation is one to many (one PositionCurrency can have many PositionResource)

```
tc_account.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getBrief()));
tc_acc_name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getName()));
tc_currency.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getBrief()));
```

Exception is:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException:   ru.com.isbank.adc.adc_common.model.position.PositionResource cannot be cast to ru.com.isbank.adc.adc_common.model.position.PositionCurrency

Comment: Create new data model say PositionResourceAndCurrencyWrapper, and put the desired fields from both model, then use this on a tableview.

Comment: At which line of code did the exception's stack trace indicate it occurred?  You should always post the full stack trace of an exception.